# letting only the creator edit a Category in django

Tags: python, django, m2m

In my web app,I have a m2m relation between a `Category` and a `User`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='category_users')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
```

When a user tries to create a Category,I do this

```
category,created = Category.objects.get_or_create(title__iexact=category_title,defaults={'title':category_title,'description':category_title})
```

I need to provide the user with an edit page for `Category`.I thought to provide it such that only the person who created the category may edit the description.
So,I tried to add a creator field in the model.

```
class Category(models.Model):
        users = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='category_users')
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.TextField()
        creator = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='category_creator')
```

However,this causes an `IntegrityError` when `get_or_create()` method is run,because `creator_id` is null

```
...
category_title = category_title_form.cleaned_data['title']
category_title = category_title.strip()
if len(category_title)>0:
            category,created = Category.objects.get_or_create(title__iexact=category_title,defaults={'title':category_title,'description':category_title})
            if request.user not in category.users.all():
                category.users.add(request.user)                
                category.save()
            if created:
                category.creator = request.user
            category.save()
```

Can someone tell me if there is a way I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user creates a category, you can add that category to the users "Category Set" --

```
category, created = user.category_set.get_or_create(
    title__iexact=category_title,
    defaults={'title': category_title, 'description': category_title}
)
```

By accessing the category table through user.category_set, the user_id field will be automatically maintained.

Only the user's categories can be retrieved through this call, and if it creates a new category, then the user_id will be set automatically.